# error C2228: left of '.push_back' must have class/struct/union

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stdvector

Just started to learn vector, but I got this error from VC++2010 and stuck there, help please....

"error C2228: left of '.push_back' must have class/struct/union"

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<double> myVector();
    double temp = 30.0;
    myVector.push_back(temp);   //this line makes error ?? why??

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Smells pretty vexing to me.

Comment: Welcome to world of vexing parsing in c++

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
vector<double> myVector();
```

this line looks like a forward declaration of a function returning vector.

It should be just

```
vector<double> myVector;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here, you are declaring a function not a vector, this is known as [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). What you currently have is being interpreted as a forward declaration of a function that takes no arguments that returns a `vector<double>`:

```
vector<double> myVector();
                       ^^
```

if you just want to use the default constructor, it needs to be:

```
vector<double> myVector ;
```

Unrelated to your current issue, I would advise against [`using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). I realize it is everywhere and it saves some typing but in the long run it will cause you problems.

Answer (score 2):

This sentence is wrong:

```
vector<double> myVector();
```

or the complier will consider the myVector a function which return a value of vector!!

you should define a vector like this:

```
vector<double> myVector
```

Comment: That simple but I do not realize it, thx....